# Multi-threading and atomicity/mem leaks

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-leaks, valgrind

So, I'm implementing a program with multiple threads (pthreads), and I am looking for help on a few points. I'm doing c++ on linux. All of my other questions have been answered by Google so far, but there are still two that I have not found answers for.

**Question 1**: I am going to be doing a bit of file I/O and web-page getting/processing within my threads. Is there anyway to guarantee what the threads do to be atomic? I am going to be letting my program run for quite a while, more than likely, and it won't really have a predetermined ending point. I am going to be catching the signal from a ctrl+c and I want to do some cleanup afterwards and still want my program to print out results/close files, etc.

I'm just wondering if it is reasonable behavior for the program to wait for the threads to complete or if I should just kill all the threads/close the file and exit. I just don't want my results to be skewed. Should I/can I just do a pthread_exit() in the signal catching method?

Any other comments/ideas on this would be nice.

**Question 2**: Valgrind is saying that I have some possible memory leaks. Are these avoidable, or does this always happen with threading in c++? Below are two of the six or so messages that I get when checking with valgrind.

I have been looking at a number of different websites, and one said that some possible memory leaks could be because of sleeping a thread. This doesn't make sense to me, nevertheless, I am currently sleeping the threads to test the setup I have right now (I'm not actually doing any real I/O at the moment, just playing with threads).

```
==14072== 256 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 4 of 6
==14072== at 0x402732C: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:467)
==14072== by 0x400FDAC: _dl_check_map_versions (dl-version.c:300)
==14072== by 0x4012898: dl_open_worker (dl-open.c:269)
==14072== by 0x400E63E: _dl_catch_error (dl-error.c:178)
==14072== by 0x4172C51: do_dlopen (dl-libc.c:86)
==14072== by 0x4052D30: start_thread (pthread_create.c:304)
==14072== by 0x413A0CD: clone (clone.S:130)
==14072== 
==14072== 630 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 5 of 6
==14072== at 0x402732C: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:467)
==14072== by 0x400A8AF: _dl_new_object (dl-object.c:77)
==14072== by 0x4006067: _dl_map_object_from_fd (dl-load.c:957)
==14072== by 0x4007EBC: _dl_map_object (dl-load.c:2250)
==14072== by 0x40124EF: dl_open_worker (dl-open.c:226)
==14072== by 0x400E63E: _dl_catch_error (dl-error.c:178)
==14072== by 0x4172C51: do_dlopen (dl-libc.c:86)
==14072== by 0x4052D30: start_thread (pthread_create.c:304)
==14072== by 0x413A0CD: clone (clone.S:130)
```

I am creating my threads with:

```
rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, thread_stall, (void *)NULL);
```

(rc = return code). At the end of the entry point, I call pthread_exit().

Comment: Yes, you can avoid memory leaks by programming correctly. Not all libraries are perfect in that aspect, and you may like to ignore errors coming from within external libraries. Also, "still reachable" isn't really a "leak", but rather a "lazy". (Which explains why it's in an external library.) A leak is a "definitely lost".

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  As it turns out, a lot of the "still reachable" memory was because I didn't join my threads before restarting them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my take:

1.If you want your threads to exit gracefully (killing them with open file or socket handles is never a good idea), have them loop on a termination flag:

```
while(!stop) 
{
    do work
}
```

Then when you catch the ctrl-c set the flag to `true` and then join them. Make sure to declare stop as `std::atomic<bool>` to make sure all the threads see the updated value. This way they will finish the current batch of work and then exit gracefully when checking the condition next time.

2.I don't have enough information about your code to answer this.